# Code to find strings in source code over many urls

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, explode, strstr

I want to enter a very long list of urls and search for specific strings within the source code, outputting a list of urls that contain the string. Sounds simple enough right? I have come up with the bellow code, the input being a html form. You can try it at pelican-cement.com/findfrog.

It seems to work half the time, but is thrown off by multiple urls/urls in different orders. Searching for 'adsense' it correctly ids politics1.com out of

```
cnn.com
politics1.com
```

however, if reversed the output is blank. How can I get reliable, consistent results? preferably something I could input thousands of urls into?

```
<html>
<body>

<?
set_time_limit (0);

$urls=explode("\n", $_POST['url']);

$allurls=count($urls);

for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= $allurls; $counter++) {

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls[$counter]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_exec ($ch); 
 $curl_scraped_page=curl_exec($ch); 

$haystack=strtolower($curl_scraped_page);
$needle=$_POST['proxy'];
if (strlen(strstr($haystack,$needle))>0) {

echo $urls[$counter];
echo "<br/>";
curl_close($ch);
}
}




//$FileNameSQL = "/googleresearch" .  abs(rand(0,1000000000000000))  .  ".csv";
//$query = "SELECT * FROM happyturtle INTO OUTFILE '$FileNameSQL' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
//$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//exit;

echo '$FileNameSQL';





?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorganized your code a bit. The main culprit was whitespace. You need to trim your URL string before using it (i.e. `trim($url);`).

Other changes:

- Set your search term outside the for loop, since it never changes.
- Setup the curl object outside the loop and reuse it by just changing the URL each time.
- Use curl_setopt_array() to set multiple curl options in one statement.
- Use a foreach loop, since you're iterating over the entire array anyway and the code is cleaner.
- Using stripos() is more efficient than strstr() and is case-insensitive anyway.
- Use the !== comparator to prevent implied typecasting (FALSE !== 0, but FALSE == 0).
- Check the returned $html string as curl_exec() can return FALSE if it fails.
- Close the curl object at the end (i.e. outside the if statement too).

The code below can be run on [my quick mockup](http://test.jamesan.ca/search.php).

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="search.php" method="post"> 
  URLs: <br/>
  <textarea rows="20" cols="50" input type="text" name="url" /></textarea><br/>

  Search Term: <br/>
  <textarea rows="20" cols="50" input type="text" name="proxy" /></textarea><br/>

  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>

<?
  if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
    set_time_limit (0);

    $urls = explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
    $term = $_POST['proxy'];
    $options = array( CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
                      CURLOPT_HEADER         => 1,
                      );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
      $html = curl_exec($ch);

      if ($html !== FALSE && stristr($html, $term) !== FALSE) { // Found!
        echo $url;
      }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem now is that it times out whenever more then 50 urls are entered. @James An

Comment: Wrapping the code in a batch process in PHP is a lot more complicated. Instead of processing the form submission immediately, you'll need to record the search term and all the URLs in a file or database. Then, call another PHP file that will process up until just before the timeout, saving results in file or database, and return an HTML file that will show the progress and automatically (refresh) call the batch PHP file again, until all URLs are processed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should call

```
curl_close($ch);
```

Regardless of whether it finds the string in the scraped page or not. Aside from that I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code.

If its not something in the code, then its probably some difference in the scraped page.  Maybe the page is dynamic, and doesn't always contain the needle word on subsequent checks.  Maybe the server of the page you were trying to scrape returned an error code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tweaks, not sure if they would help but still

```
$url_to_go = trim($urls[$counter]);
if($url_to_go){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_to_go);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 $curl_scraped_page=curl_exec($ch); 
 curl_close($ch);

 // more code follows
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be carriage returns/whitespace around the URLs that is throwing it off? It might be worth putting in a

```
$urls[$counter] = trim($urls[$counter]);
```

at the start of your for loop.

Also:

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    [...]
}
```

is a more efficient way of checking if one string contains another. You could also use stripos here instead of strtolower()'ing the whole thing first (not sure if that would improve things).