# Code to find strings in source code over many urls-timeout issue

Tags: php, arrays, curl, timeout, web-scraping

I want to enter a very long list of urls and search for specific strings within the source code, outputting a list of urls that contain the string. Sounds simple enough right? I have the bellow code, you can try it at pelican-cement.com/findfrog.

The problem is that it times out every time I search for over 10 or so urls

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="search.php" method="post"> 
  URLs: <br/>
  <textarea rows="20" cols="50" input type="text" name="url" /></textarea><br/>

  Search Term: <br/>
  <textarea rows="20" cols="50" input type="text" name="proxy" /></textarea><br/>

  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>

<?
set_time_limit (0);
  if(isset($_POST['url'])) {


    $urls = explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
    $term = $_POST['proxy'];
    $options = array( CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
                      CURLOPT_HEADER         => 1,
                      );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
      $html = curl_exec($ch);

      if ($html !== FALSE && stristr($html, $term) !== FALSE) { // Found!
        echo $url;
        echo "<br>";
      }
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo "space";
  }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to find strings in source code over many urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642414/code-to-find-strings-in-source-code-over-many-urls)

Comment: Yes. That's how it is. Many requests take up time. No magic solution for that.

Comment: It is the same code, but this is a different issue. I can wait, the problem is that it times out early. Issue is not taking time, but not returning results.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the time limit.

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  set_time_limit(120);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is 2 minutes for each url